# Set metadata between flow tables in OpenFlow enabled switch without interacting with the controller

Tags: sdn, openflow

In my OpenFlow enabled switch, the incoming packets pass through multiple flow tables. The packet and its metadata are passed between the tables. Can I put one of the packet header values (e.g. 32 bit tcp source port) into the metadata field? Based on the installed flow entry, I can put fixed data into the metadata field but not packet related data such as value of tcp port etc.

One way is to send a packet-in msg to the controller with a cloned copy of the packet. The controller replies back with a flow mod where tcp source port value can be placed in the metadata field. But I want to do it without interacting with the controller. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

I think it's go against to the idea of 'software defined' networking, beacuse it means that the switch is now have some ability to 'handle' the packets. Plus, I don't think that this 'put one of the packet header values (e.g. 32 bit tcp source port) into the metadata field' is the way to use metadata. Metadata is more like an ID to combined with a certain flow entry to indicate that the packet can match this flow entry.